# detect an alphabetical character in a picture using JES

Tags: python, jython, detect

I have a task that asked me to making two TEXT picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov7yT.png) which one of them is only one character [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei9Yk.png) to detect on the TEXT picture.

the first task is to detect only one character location and I sorted it out, but the second task is to detect all the characters location in it.

It says that I have to copy, and paste the detectOneChar() and extend it by numbers of alphabetical including "space" meaning 27 times. but I did not understand how to do.

This is my first code:

```
def driver():
  src=makePicture(pickAFile())
  tgt=makePicture(pickAFile())
  for myOffset in range(0,getWidth(tgt)-getWidth(src)):
    detectOneChar(src,tgt,myOffset,0)
  explore(tgt)
  return tgt

def detectOneChar(src,tgt,xOffset,yOffset):
  sWidth=getWidth(src)
  sHeight=getHeight(src)
  matchPixels=0
  perfectMatch=sWidth*sHeight
  for sX in range (0,sWidth):
    for sY in range (0,sHeight):
      tX=sX+xOffset
      tY=sY+yOffset
      sPx=getPixel(src,sX,sY)
      tPx=getPixel(tgt,tX,tY)
      if getColor(tPx) == getColor(sPx):
        matchPixels=matchPixels+1
      if matchPixels == perfectMatch:
        print "Found L at position", tX
  setColor(tPx,getColor(sPx))
```

Answer (score -1):

i cant see if your functions works, everything it prints out just the file path, however, it is recommended using an array and create a list of letter inside